# "Truncate" number to lie in a range quickly in R

Tags: r, built-in

Is there any simple built-in R function or quick hack to set a given number to lie in a given range if it isn't already? I want something that does this:

```
truncate <- function(x,a,b) min(max(x,a),b)
```

which is of course simple but seems like it should be built in. I know truncation has a different meaning in R (cutting off decimals), but it has my meaning in, e.g., probability and statistics.

Comment: What do you mean by *"a given number to lie in a given range"*? Do you want to randomly sample a number from the interval `(a, b)`, e.g. for uniform sampling something like `runif(1, min = a, max = b)`? There also exist various R packages that implement methods to sample from a range of truncated distributions.

Comment: It looks like it's just "if `x < a`, set `x` to `a`, if `x > b`, set `x` to `b`".

Comment: To be or not to be vectorized?

Answer (score 3):

Some (vectorised) options, including `microbenchmark`

```
set.seed(2019)
x <- sample(1:1000, 10^6, replace = T)

# Option 1: Using replace
truncate1 <- function(x, a, b) {
    replace(replace(x, x < a, a), x > b, b)
}

# Option 2: Direct indexing
truncate2 <- function(x, a, b) {
    x[x < a] <- a
    x[x > b] <- b
    x
}

# Option 3: Using vectorised min/max
truncate3 <- function(x, a, b) pmin(pmax(x, a), b)

# Option 4: Rcpp version
library(Rcpp)
cppFunction("
    NumericVector truncate4(NumericVector x, double a, double b) {
        x[x < a] = a;
        x[x > b] = b;
        return(x);
    }
    ")

library(microbenchmark)
res <- microbenchmark(
    truncate1 = truncate1(x, 20, 50),
    truncate2 = truncate2(x, 20, 50),
    truncate3 = truncate3(x, 20, 50),
    truncate4 = truncate4(x, 20, 50))
#Unit: milliseconds
#      expr      min       lq     mean   median       uq      max neval
# truncate1 21.11311 24.72446 28.53179 26.93042 30.36175 67.24833   100
# truncate2 18.92472 23.04515 28.72290 26.33326 29.27687 76.96418   100
# truncate3 15.25429 17.89847 23.96331 21.31570 24.56693 63.58878   100
# truncate4 24.37332 27.33767 32.30241 29.97932 33.41832 72.65265   100
```

Comment: adding `pmin` and `pmax` to the benchmark would be interesting

Comment: Yeah not surprised that min-max is fastest. I guess there's probably no built-in since a few people have seen this but I'll wait a day or so to see if anyone finds something and then accept this.

Comment: @SheridanGrant Yes, vectorised min/max is slightly faster than the other methods; I'm not sure if I expected that though. I guess `pmin`/`pmax` is highly optimised for vectors. PS. I also added an `Rcpp` version because I was interested how it would compare.

Comment: Cool--presumably the fixed costs of Rcpp are too high to make it worthwhile except for huge vectors...